# D3 sort an array of objects on 2 object properties

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I have a dataset with an array of objects holding 4 object properties like so :

```js
var dataset = [{
    key: 0,
    brand: "A",
    value: 10,
    size: 10
}, {
    key: 1,
    brand: "B",
    value: 11,
    size: 10
}, {
    key: 2,
    brand: "C",
    value: 12,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 3,
    brand: "D",
    value: 13,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 4,
    brand: "E",
    value: 14,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 5,
    brand: "G",
    value: 15,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 6,
    brand: "F",
    value: 16,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 7,
    brand: "H",
    value: 17,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 8,
    brand: "I",
    value: 18,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 9,
    brand: "J",
    value: 19,
    size: 9
}, {
    key: 10,
    brand: "K",
    value: 20,
    size: 9
}];
```

I then build a graph with D3 showing the `value` as horizontal lines and the `size` as bubbles sitting on top of the lines (please see http://jsfiddle.net/G74Aq/4/).

I added a sort function for each of the above object properties apart from the `key` property which is used for the key function in the sort. This works fine when sorting by name and by value, but when I sort by size lines and bubbles get sorted differently. Note that this only happens if the key value goes up to 10, suggesting lexicographical sort issues, which I thought I could bypass by adding 0's in front each key number below <10 (which didn't change anything).

My question is : why are the different elements sorted in a different way even though the sort methods applied are all using the same key function? And, naturally, how can I align the sort  functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing it to sort by numerical value instead of string. The unary `+` operator can accomplish that.

```
function getSortFunction(propertyName) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return +(a[propertyName]) > +(b[propertyName]);
    }
}

dataset.sort(getSortFunction("size"));
```

Comment: It definitely cuts down the code, but doesn't seem to affect the sorting issues. I've updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/G74Aq/8/). Could it be there is a confusion between the `d.key` value and the array index `i` I use in order to determine the x position?